# React Router: navigate to /compose/tweet but keep orthogonal previous route (like: /notifications) mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am seeking to recreate a pattern with React Router. It is best described by the Twitter example: as you hit the Tweet button, the browser navigates to `/compose/tweet`, mounting the composer component. However, *and that's the key*, the previous route (`/home`, `/explore`, `/notifications`, `/messages`) is kept mounted despite the route change. How do you do that?

This could be called bidimensional routing: the `/compose/tweet` route is kept orthogonal with respect to the other routes that render the main view. The other routes are hidden (i.e., not in the address bar any longer) upon navigating to `/compose/tweet`, thereby rendering two independent routes (say, `/notifications` and `/compose/tweet`) at once.

My actual example: I need to show a user settings menu (`/user/menu`) as a large sidebar, but I do not want that to change whether the user was navigating `/` (the homepage), `/faq`, `/contact`, etc. Based on my current understanding of React Router, as soon as you hit `/user/menu`, any other route (take `/faq` as an example) would be unmounted based on route match.

Caching the previous route (e.g., Redux, which I'm using extensively already) does not seem feasible, since, even though I would be able to redirect the user to the previous route upon exiting `/user/menu`, React would still be unmounting components, in fact showing the homepage in the background until the user exits `/user/menu` & gets redirected to where they were at, which is not the intended behaviour. I would want the rest of the page to stay there with the rendered components, just the way Twitter does.

Am I overlooking anything? Is this an easy pattern and I am missing something?

Note: it's a SSR isomorphic app, but I guess/hope that won't change things.

Comment: `react-router-dom` `Router` component can match and render multiple routes simultaneously. For example `"/"`, `"/users/"`, `"/users/menu"` can all be matched at the same time. `Route` component can also specify multiple paths to match on.

Comment: How to render /faq and /user/menu simultaneously then, given the address bar now only contains /user/menu & the user was previously visiting /faq?

Comment: That's the same use case as Twitter, by the way: rendering /compose/tweet and /notifications simultaneously, with only /compose/tweet on the address bar & /notifications as the last route before hitting the Tweet button.

Answer (score 1):

Despite Adam Abramov's suggestion to keep React Router as the source of truth for whatever can be passed as route, and avoid deep integrations between Router and Redux, I found myself having to use Redux as the main source of truth in this (important) use case. I still wanted to have `Route` components for SSR and SEO purposes.

So, I created my own `MultidimensionalSwitch` and `MultidimensionalRoute` components to solve this use case. If a `MultidimensionalSwitch` is mounted, it will render the components at their subroutes, but if none of them is matched, it will render them based on another dimension, which is provided by Redux at an additional `alt` property of the corresponding `MultidimensionalRoute`.

Here below is some code, feel free to answer/ask should you need more info about it.

**Main**

```
class _Main extends Component {
    render() {
        const {menuOpen,selected} = this.props;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Route exact path={exactRoutes.ROOT}      component={() => <Redirect to={selected?exactRoutes[selected]:exactRoutes.HOME} />} />
                <Header />
                <Route       path={nestedRoutes.AUTH+routeParams.LOGIN_SIGNUP.key}      component={ScreenAuth} />
                <Route       path={exactRoutes.USER_MENU}                               component={ScreenUser} />
                {!menuOpen?"":<ScreenMenu />}
                <ScreenMain>
                    <MultidimensionalSwitch>
                        <MultidimensionalRoute path={exactRoutes.HOME}          alt={selected===guestMenuOption.HOME}           component={GuestHome} />
                        <MultidimensionalRoute path={exactRoutes.USER}          alt={selected===guestMenuOption.USER}           component={User} />
                        <MultidimensionalRoute path={exactRoutes.VISION}        alt={selected===guestMenuOption.VISION}         component={GuestVision} />
                        <MultidimensionalRoute path={exactRoutes.FAQ}           alt={selected===guestMenuOption.FAQ}            component={GuestFaq} />
                        <MultidimensionalRoute path={exactRoutes.INFOGRAPHICS}  alt={selected===guestMenuOption.INFOGRAPHICS}   component={GuestInfographics} />
                        <MultidimensionalRoute path={exactRoutes.BLOG}          alt={selected===guestMenuOption.BLOG}           component={GuestBlog} />
                        <MultidimensionalRoute path={exactRoutes.CONTACT}       alt={selected===guestMenuOption.CONTACT}        component={GuestContact} />
                    </MultidimensionalSwitch>
                    <Footer />
                </ScreenMain>
                <Flare />
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    menuOpen:           state.client.guest.menuOpen,
    selected:           state.client.guest.guestMenuOption,
});

const Main = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{})(_Main));

export default Main;
```

**MultidimensionalSwitch**

```
class _MultidimensionalSwitch extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Switch>
                    {this.props.children}
                    {this.props.children.map(child => !child.props.alt?"":<Route path={nestedRoutes.ROOT} component={child.props.component} />)}
                </Switch>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    selected:           state.client.guest.guestMenuOption,
});

const MultidimensionalSwitch = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{})(_MultidimensionalSwitch));

export default MultidimensionalSwitch;
```

**MultidimensionalRoute**

```
class _MultidimensionalRoute extends Component {
    render() {
        const {path,component} = this.props;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Route exact path={path} component={component} />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => ({
    path:               ownProps.path,
    component:          ownProps.component,
});

const MultidimensionalRoute = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{})(_MultidimensionalRoute));

export default MultidimensionalRoute;
```